# How to send data to a Linux terminal

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

I need to send data to a Linux terminal, in this manner that terminal could receive the data with scanf? there is any way to do that?

I tried to write my desired data to /proc/pid/fd/1 with below command, however, I can see the written data in the terminal but scanf couldn't catch that data and still wait for the user to enter data.

```
printf "85\n"  > /proc/24737/fd/1
```

Comment: You're writing to their output terminal, not stuffing into their input.

Comment: You can't do it in general. If their input is a pty, you need to write to the master end of the pty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very interesting question, and there is no easy way (that I know of) to write to a another terminal using the file descriptors.
see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385771/writing-to-stdin-of-a-process

However, Unix and Linux, have many great ways for IPC (inter process communication). You might want to looking into pipes, named pipes, or Sockets.

Depending on what you are doing you might think about popen, or screen.

You probably don't want to write to the terminal, but the task that is running on the terminal? Can you change how the task is invoked (called)? Do you need to use standard in for other things?

If you explain your use case, we will try to direct you better.

Comment: Thank you so much, named pipe has solved my problem.